# Expalanation for errors in the below code

Tags: php

```
if(!is_dir($dir_path))
    {
        $mk_dir=mkdir($dir_path, 0777);
        $ch_mod=chmod($dir_path, 0777);
    }
```

In the above code I am getting errors like below:

Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir0]: No such file or directory in E:\salaahakardb\New Folder\xampp\htdocs\extramarks2\jnrcontent\fillblanks\form_vars.php on line 66

Warning: chmod() [function.chmod0]: No such file or directory in E:\salaahakardb\New Folder\xampp\htdocs\extramarks2\jnrcontent\fillblanks\form_vars.php on line 67

Please explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent directory of the directory you're trying to create probably doesn't exist.

One way could be to create it recursively:

```
mkdir($dir_path, 0777, true);
```

Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php for further info.

Also you can get rid of that chmod() since you are already setting permissions while mkdir()'ing.

Answer (score 0):

is_dir function returns false, if passed parameter is file - it's your situation.
try [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) function